# How to use the npm packages while using react in html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to place a react component inside an **HTML** file and render it accordingly.
I have a [`lottie-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lottie) component that I have used in my react file but the problem is I don't know how to import the same package using [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/).

I have followed the documentation for [Add React to Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) and had built this code structure for HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>React version</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- root div for rendering the carousel -->
    <div class="ReactCustom"></div>

    <!-- few scripts for react  -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- some of the custom packages used in this project -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/lottie-react@2.1.0/build/index.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- all the js file import -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="Trial.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<Trial />, document.querySelector('.ReactCustom'));
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

And here is the `Trail.js` file structure.

```
function Trial() {
  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      <div className="boxStyles">
        <Lottie
        animationData={`./animations/EARBUD.json`}
        loop
        autoPlay
        className={styles.animationStyle}
      />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Doing this, I am getting an error in the console.

Error Says:

```
babel.min.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: https://unpkg.com/browse/lottie-react@2.1.0/build/index.js: Unexpected token (1:1)
```

Please Help!!

Thank you!!

More updates:

New Errors-

```
index.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

and

```
react-dom.production.min.js:141 ReferenceError: Lottie is not defined
```

Pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong url: [this](https://unpkg.com/browse/lottie-react@2.1.0/build/index.js) points to the `browse` part of unpkg, useful when you need to see the content of files.

If you need to use the actual code in order to import it in your html, you need to use the `raw` that you can access with `View Raw` button (e.g. [this](https://unpkg.com/lottie-react@2.1.0/build/index.js)).

**EDIT**

Add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.min.js" crossorigin></script>`
under the import of `react` and then edit the import of `lottie-react` with `<script type="text/babel" src="https://unpkg.com/lottie-react@2.1.0/build/index.umd.js" crossorigin></script>`

Comment: Thank You!! Yes, your answer is correct but now I am getting few more errors.
I will mention them in the edits.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it out.

Comment: Still the same problem but, there isn't an export problem.

Comment: Is seems that `lottie-react` can't be used without bundling. Can't you use webpack or similar?

Comment: Can we do this using webpack?
I would like to know how!!

Comment: I suggest you to take a read here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app. It's really simple and I'm sure that you will be able to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235221/discussion-between-satyam-and-marco-nisi).